# Is there a name for a "continuous space of sequences"?

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity, terminology, sheaf-theory, fiber-bundles

> Is there a name for a "continuous space of sequences" in the following sense?

i.e. let $f:X\mapsto X$ be a continuous surjective but not necessarily injective function over some compact toplogical space $X$.

Then let $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ define some sequence $S_{x0}=(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)$

Then there is a clear sense in which these sequences $S_{x}$ are continuous in the space $X$.  How is this concept of a continuous sequence space described or named?  I've previously encountered phrases fibre bundle and sheaf which may be related but reading the definitions I'm struggling to tell if either of these is the appropriate concept or where else to look.

Comment: Is there a reason to limit yourself to surjective functions?

Comment: How do you define 'continuity' of sequences? If you mean *pointwise* (i.e. *coordinatewise*) convergence of sequences (or nets) of sequences of $X$, then it's simply the topological space $X^\omega$.

Comment: @Arthur only because the special case I have in mind is surjective and I thought it could matter.  On reflection, it seems to strengthen the idea of continuity in that it means every two points $x_n,y_n$ that are close together in some pair of sequences $X_n,Y_n$, will have predecessors $x_{n-1},y_{n-1}$ that are close together.  So every sequence is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$

Comment: @Berci I mean the definition of continuous given in the question, i.e. sequences have this continuity property if every sequence is an orbit of the same function $f$ which is itself continuous on the topological space.  The orbit of a function is the path it takes on iteration.  Therefore this implies that if any two points $x_n,y_m$ drawn from some pair of sequences $X_{x0},Y_{y0}$ are close together, then $x_{n+1},y_{m+1}$ and (assuming the function is surjective, $x_{n-1},y_{m-1}$ will also be close together.

Comment: @Arthur sorry not necessarily $\Bbb Z$, it could be any cyclic group finite or otherwise.